# Closing a question due to lack of research

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Why is it not possible in Christianity.SE to flag a question as being off-topic due to lack of research? I wanted to flag [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60798/what-was-meaning-of-talent-as-used-by-jesus-in-his-parable) as such, since the OP could have found an answer by looking in a dictionary, but the option does not appear to exist.

Edit: The OP did do relevant research, so my mistake there. However, it might still be useful to have this flag.

Comment: I see you have a lot of rep on ELU. Closing for lack of research is particular to that site, because they get so many bad questions. This site gets far fewer questions in general, and most aren't so poorly/lazily researched.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yeah! We're always reaching for that particular button (either that, or "proofreading").

Comment: On that talent question I'm still unsure that OP was asking for a simple definition. I tried to draw him out about what he was looking for but have not gotten a clear response. And the answer that gives a definition has not been accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Lack of research" isn't a reason to close questions. It is a reason to down-vote them: if you hover over the vote buttons on questions the primary tip for using those functions does involve judging the level of research/investment in the question. I would encourage downvoting questions that don't do basic research in order to form a well reasoned question. However there isn't a cookie-cutter close reason for that because we don't actually close questions based on that parameter.

Often questions with that issue will *also* have some other reason that is valid for closure (such as being too broad), in which case you can vote to close based on that criteria (and also vote!).